# java virtual methods: feature or bug?

Tags: java, dalvik, jvm-languages

Take this base class:

```
public abstract class XMPPSubservice
{

    protected XMPPService mTheService;


    protected XMPPSubservice(Context context) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, XMPPService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }


    public void onServiceInstance(XMPPService service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mTheService = service;
    }

}
```

And this derived class:

```
public class PublicDataSubservice extends XMPPSubservice 
{

    private final SomeObject mObj = new SomeObject();

    public PublicDataSubservice(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceInstance(XMPPService service) 
    {
        super.onServiceInstance(service);
            mObj.doSomethingWith(mTheService);
    }

}
```

The goal was to only call mObj.doSomethingWith(mTheService); after the mTheService became valid (which happened in the base class). Thing was it always spat out NPE at the mObj line. I can understand why that happened, but it looks wonky to me. So is this a bug or a feature of DVM ? How about JVM ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's entirely correct, and would occur in "vanilla" Java too.

Instance variable initializers are only executed at the start of the constructor body *after* the superclass constructor has completed executing. So while the `XMPPSubservice` constructor is executing, `mObj` is null - you then call a virtual method from the constructor, and the override in `PublicDataService` executes.

Moral: don't call virtual methods from constructors, unless you *really* have to, in which case you should document them really carefully. (Very occasionally it's useful, but you should try hard to avoid it.) Basically it means you end up with a call on a potentially-partially-initialized object, which is what's happening here.

Comment: For more examples of various problems resulting from calling overridden methods from a constructor, see Josh Bloch's _Effective Java_

Comment: >>virtual methods from constructors. Doh!... where have I heard that before ? in college maybe. Good reminder! Although Android made it less obvious I was doing just that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following using stub implementations of your objects in a Java VM.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Context context = new Context();
    PublicDataSubservice pds = new PublicDataSubservice(context);
    XMPPService service = new XMPPService();
    pds.onServiceInstance(service);
}
```

No `NullPointerException`.

Am I missing something? I guess that `onServiceInstance` must actually get called as a result of `context.getService(intent)`?